# How to get focused view frame size in tvOS?

Tags: swift, tvos

How can I get the size of a focused view in tvOS?

I need its size to move a label from within the view to a new position that fits the focused frame.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `focusedFrameGuide` that `UIImageView` provides.

Using the `imageview.focusedFrameGuide.layoutFrame` you can determine how to reposition your label.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately, I can't test if this is the correct answer.

Comment: When setting `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` the`'frame` is different from the `focusedFrameGuide`. So I think it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Auto Layout you need to set two constraints:

```swift
focusedConstraint = label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.focusedFrameGuide.bottomAnchor)
unfocusedConstraint = label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor)
```

And activate/deactivate on `didUpdateFocus`:

```swift
    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

        if context.nextFocusedView == self {
            unfocusedConstraint?.isActive = false
            focusedConstraint?.isActive = true
        } else if context.previouslyFocusedView == self {
            focusedConstraint?.isActive = false
            unfocusedConstraint?.isActive = true
        }

        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```